# PHP Script crashes IE6

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer-6

The code below crashes IE6 for some reason. Much as IE is god-awful, i have never seen this before. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<div id="edit">
<?php 

$a = $_POST['category'];
if ($a == "")
{
    $a = $_GET['category'];
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE related_page_id = $a && type= 'copy'");

?>

<table width="460px;">
    <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Associated Images</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr style='vertical-align:top'><td>$row[title]</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='addimage.php?id=$row[id]&&category=$a'>Add image/file</a>";
    echo "<td><a href='change.php?id=$row[id]&&category=$a'>edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=$row[id]&&category=$a'>delete</a></td>";
    echo "<td>";

    $id = $row['id'];
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE assets = $id");
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        echo "<a href='$row1[path]'>$row1[title]</a> | <a href='delete.php?id=$row1[id]&&category=$a'>remove?</a><br />";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
if($a == 1 || $a == 3 || $a == 5){
}else{
    echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan='5'><a href='change.php?id=0&&category=$a'>New Item</a></td></tr>";
}

?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post generated HTML as it crashes IE, not the PHP code.

Comment: You really need to either use a parameterized query (see the MDB2 PEAR library) or call mysql_real_escape_string() on $a before including it in a query string, or you'll leave yourself open to SQL injections.  Alternatively, if it's always supposed to be a number, call intval() on it first.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it's the reason for the crash, but the `td` tag in the line

```
echo "<td><a href='addimage.php?id=$row[id]&&category=$a'>Add image/file</a>";
```

is not closed. Also:

```
</div>
</div>
</div>
</table>
```

should be:

```
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Furthermore - for security reasons - check if `$a` is numeric before using it in the query below.

```
$a = $_POST['category'];
if ($a == "")
{
        $a = $_GET['category'];
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE related_page_id = $a && type= 'copy'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The generated code doesn't crash IE6 for me. It could probably be one of your stylesheets or javascript though, or maybe it's just my setup (IE6 is used as a standalone browser here).

Also, why do you have those double ampersands? Are you sure you don't want to use `&amp;` instead?

Comment: Agreed. It's the HTML crashing the browser, not the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

here is the generated code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
            theme : "advanced"
        });
    </script>


    <title>Chapman Corp Site - CMS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/admin.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Chapman" charset="utf-8" />
        <!--[if lte IE 6]> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/unitpngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id ="content">
<p><a href="index.php">Home</a></p><div id="edit">

<table width="460px;">
    <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Associated Images</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<tr style='vertical-align:top'><td>Home</td><td><a href='addimage.php?id=77&&category=1'>Add image/file</a><td><a href='change.php?id=77&&category=1'>edit</a></td><td><a href='delete.php?id=77&&category=1'>delete</a></td><td><a href='../uploads/footer.jpg'>footer.jpg</a> | <a href='delete.php?id=88&&category=1'>remove?</a><br /></td></tr></div>

</div>
</div>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Drew: Remove the line <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/unitpngfix.js"></script> and then see if that still crashes the page.